# Error LNK2019 in visual studio in win32 application?

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2013, lnk2019, msvcrt

I have making an attempt at writing my first program in Visual Studio, however am being troubled by an error.
It says: -

```
    Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wWinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup    
E:\Documents\Programming\Software Development\Microsoft Development\Microsoft Development\MSVCRTD.lib(wcrtexew.obj) 
Microsoft Development
```

On researching I found similar errors, but none have helped me solve the problem.
I have changed the entry point to

```
wWinMainCRTStartup
```

the character set to Unicode

the subsystem to console. The project is a win32 application. The code is as follows: -

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
    {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hello World!", "Note", 1/*MB_OK*/);
    printf("nCmdShow = %d\n", nCmdShow);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I fix this issue?

P.S. I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Unicode build your code needs to be more like this:

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
    {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Hello World!", L"Note", 1/*MB_OK*/);
    printf(L"nCmdShow = %d\n", nCmdShow);
    return 0;
}
```

At least by default this will be set to use the Windows subsystem (because the entry point is named a variant of WinMain). You can force that to the console subsystem (`-subsystem:console` flag to the linker) or get it to happen by default by changing the entry point to a variant of `main` instead:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv) { // ...
```

Obviously you won't be able to print `nCmdShow` using this though (not that it really means anything in a console program). For that matter, since you're not using the command line arguments anyway, you can simplify this somewhat to:

```
int wmain(){ // ....
```

Actually, `nCmdShow` is basically obsolete even for windowed programs. The first time a windowed program calls `ShowWindow`, it normally passes `nCmdShow` as the parameter. Windows, in turn, **ignores** the value passed in the first call to `ShowWindow`, and instead uses the value from the process' `STARTUPINFO` structure. Only in subsequent calls to `ShowWindow` is the parameter used (and for these subsequent calls, you're not supposed to pass `nCmdShow` either--you're supposed to pass one of the defined constants such as `SW_SHOWNORMAL`).

Reference: [MSDN entry for ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A Win32 application starts at WinMain. A console application starts at main. Your question implies you have a confused mixture of the two.

Just use the File, New, Project menu command to let Visual Studio build a skeleton of the type of application you have in mind.